# From ESRI:103300 to EPSG:4326 in SQL Server

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, epsg

This question is more or less a sequel to [Performance of joining tables on a geometry column with SQL Server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299467)

As explained in the above link, I have a shapefile that I upload to my SQL Server DB using the Shape2Sql.exe tool. Then, I'm checking whether my sets of coordinates are located inside one of the polygons given by the shapefile.

The situation has however slightly changed because I now take into account the remarks I got, which still gives this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable1 (
       FULL_ADDRESS varchar(120) NULL,
       LONGITUDE varchar(50) NULL,
       LATITUDE varchar(50) NULL
                           )

CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable2 (
       POLYGON_NAME nvarchar(255) NULL,
       geom geometry NULL
                           )
```

But I then do this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable1
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_myTable1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FULL_ADDRESS);

ALTER TABLE myTable1 
ADD geom geometry;

UPDATE myTable1 
SET geom=geometry::STGeomFromWKB((geography::Point(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 4326)).STAsBinary(), 4326); 

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX table_gist ON myTable1(geom) 
    WITH (BOUNDING_BOX = (minLong, minLat, maxLong, maxLat)) ON [PRIMARY];
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX table_gist_2 ON myTable2(geom) 
    WITH (BOUNDING_BOX = (minLong, minLat, maxLong, maxLat)) ON [PRIMARY];
```

After that, I can join my tables with some pretty good performance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      mt1.FULL_ADDRESS
    , mt1.LONGITUDE
    , mt1.LATITUDE
    , mt2.POLYGON_NAME
INTO #TEMP_TABLE
FROM myTable1 mt1
LEFT JOIN myTable2 mt2 
  ON mt2.geom.STIntersects(mt1.geom) = 1
```

With my first shapefile, it was perfectly working. Then I had to play with another file and it all of a sudden stopped being fun. I couldn't find any set of coordinates intersecting my polygons. I eventually ended up locating the problem: while my first shapefile was encoded in [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326), the second one uses [ESRI:103300](https://epsg.io/103300).

Therefore, instead of having those nice coordinates that I'm used to...

[image: EPSG:4326 polygons]

... I now get those weird ones:

[image: ESRI:103300 polygons]

It surprised me because, when using my Shape2Sql.exe tool, I always check the 'Set SRID 4326' option. I also tried the following line of code:

```
UPDATE myTable2 SET geom.STSrid=4326;
```

But it doesn't work either. That doesn't change anything to my polygons.

I'd like to find a trick so that my query can find in which polygons my points are located, like it used to do.

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments, I gave a try at the ogr2ogr solution with the following command that was inspired by the [Is it possible to reproject spatial data using SQL Server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/is-it-possible-to-reproject-spatial-data-using-sql-server) topic:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe ^
 -f "MSSQLSpatial"^
 "MSSQL:server=DestServerName;database=DestDbName;trusted_connection=yes"^
 "MSSQL:server=SourceServerName;database=SourceDbName;trusted_connection=yes"^
 -sql "SELECT [POLYGON_NAME], [geom].STAsText() geom FROM [SourceDbName].[dbo].[myTable2]"^
 -nln "myTable2"^
 -overwrite^
 -s_srs ESRI:103300^
 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

But I now have this error message:

> ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: ESRI:103300

**EDIT2:** This version however seems to work:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe ^
 -f "MSSQLSpatial"^
 "MSSQL:server=DestServerName;database=DestDbName;trusted_connection=yes"^
 "MSSQL:server=SourceServerName;database=SourceDbName;trusted_connection=yes"^
 -sql "SELECT [POLYGON_NAME], [geom].STAsText() geom FROM [SourceDbName].[dbo].[myTable2]"^
 -nln "myTable2"^
 -overwrite^
 -s_srs http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/103300/^
 -t_srs http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/
```

I then did this (I followed the same [instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/is-it-possible-to-reproject-spatial-data-using-sql-server)):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable2
ADD geom2 geometry;

UPDATE myTable2
SET geom2 = geometry::STGeomFromText(geom, 103300);
```

But it gives me this:

> Implicit conversion from data type geometry to nvarchar is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: you need to **reproject** the points not simply *label* them as being lat/lon

Comment: How does it work precisely? I'm kind of a newbie, sorry :/

Comment: You are used to geographic coordinates, but now you have planar and metric coordinates. So steps to be undertaken are to transform your coordinates into geographic coordinates and change the underlying datum. I think postgis can do this for you, but it may not know ESRI:103300. Theres a code on https://epsg.io/103300 to make this known to postgis.

Comment: There is no solution for SQL Server then? I read that the _sys.spatial_reference_systems_ table can't be changed in SQL Server. How about the reprojection suggested by @IanTurton? How can I do that?

Comment: I don't use SQL Server, but maybe Shape2Sql.exe takes an option to reproject, or check out ogr2ogr which will

Comment: Note: EPSG has added a combined Adams/Juneau WISCRS definition using WKID 8225. Esri added each county separately. I work for Esri and help maintain EPSG dataset.

Comment: I tried the ogr2ogr solution but I got this message: _ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: ESRI:103300_. Don't know if there is a workaround for that...

Comment: Can you guys have a look at my edits? I might be close to a solution but I really don't know...